# Why i cant get the process that exist on print?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os 
import time 
os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\ProcessList.txt PROCESS get Caption') 
with open('C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\ProcessList.txt', 'r') as f:
    if str('System') in f:
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
```

Comment: it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, and it was needed some little modification. I did that, but didn't get desirable result. It write successfully in a mentioned file. So, I though it would be better if I print out each line in my python IDLE. I got such weird result.

[image]

At first, it looked fine, when open in any text editor. But later, after finding this weird space between each character, I opened this file in Sublime editor, run over there, then found something look like this

[image]

After googling a little bit, I found that this is a `NUL` terminator used to teminate the string in C\C++. Maybe someone with more knowledge about this can explain it better.

I have no idea, how and why it is adding it after every character. But if you remove that and run again the code, you'll get the desirable result.

Kindly find the below updated code:

```
import os
import time

os.system('WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\Users\sohan.tirpude\Documents\LogInLog.txt PROCESS get Caption')

searchfile = open("C:\Users\sohan.tirpude\Documents\LogInLog.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    line = line.replace('\0', '')
    #print line
    if 'System' in line:
        print "Yes"
        break
    else:
        print "No"
```

Kindly give it a try.